# python processing a log file and stripping characters

Tags: python

I am making a quick log parse tool:

```
findme = 'important '
logf = file('new.txt')
newlines = []

    for line in logf:
        if findme in line:
            line.partition("as follows: ")[2]
            newlines.append(line) 


outfile = file('out.txt', 'w')
outfile.writelines(newlines)
```

Not sure how I should go about using something like partition to remove the text "as follows: " and everything before it on a per line basis. I get no error, but the text I am trying to strip remains in the output.

Comment: don't use `file` use `open`. And this doesn't even look like a syntactically valid Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plus, I'm a little confused about the line

```
line.partition("as follows: ")[2]
```

. It simply does nothing. Maybe you wanted

```
line = line.partition("as follows")[2]
```

? By the way, it ist better to just write each line in the for loop instead of a giant `writelines` at the end. Your current solution will use lots of memory for large files and not work at all with infinite files.

That final version would look like this:

```
findme = 'important '
outfile = open('out.txt', 'w')
for line in open('new.txt'):
    if findme in line:
        outfile.write(line.partition('as follows: ')[2])
```

Answer (score 1):

here's with regex

```
import re

findme = 'important ' 
pat = re.compile('.*(%s)?.*as follows: ((?(1).*\n|.*%s.*\n))' % (findme,findme))

with open('new.txt','r') as logf, open('out.txt','w') as outfile:
    for line in logf:
        m = pat.match(line)
        if m: outfile.write( m.group(2) )
```

The advantage is that it enables to search for more particular items than just with a **'if findme in line'** instruction
For example, with `findme = '(?<!A)AAA(?!A)'` , it will search on the basis of strict **'AAA'**, not *'AAAA'*.